# Is performance of "Math.abs()" better than expression with "if"?

Tags: java, performance, double, boxing

I have expression:

```
Double getAbs(Double value){
return value> 0 ? value: value== 0 ? null : -value;
}
```

or better:

```
 Double getAbs(Double value){
return Math.abs(value);
}
```

I understand that there are some differences about NaN. But method Math.abs(double) - so we have unboxing.
In which case performance better?

Comment: You need unboxing in **both** samples, so *that* is not the difference.

Comment: And: as I've told you in your earlier post: **don't guess** about your performance bottleneck. **Profile your applicaton** and *only then* try to fix the hotspots.

Comment: Why do you need to wrap Math.abs in your own method? The call overhead alone would cause performance loss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only "performance" in your code is that the JVM will need to unbox your `Double` to `double`.

`Math.abs(double)` uses a ternary if statement as follows:

```
public static double abs(double a) {
    return (a <= 0.0D) ? 0.0D - a : a;
}
```

So, your `if` statement is no performance worry at all.

Comment: +1: In both cases, the JVM is smart enough to turn either into a single machine code instruction.  Using your own, slightly different `?:` expression risks confusing the JIT compiler, so it can only be slower.

Answer (score 4):

No usually, `Math.abs()` is not slower than yours. Because JVM can implement its math operation according to the target machine. and It can be faster than your implementation.

> Code generators are encouraged
>   to use platform-specific native libraries or microprocessor
>   instructions, where available, to provide higher-performance
>   implementations of Math methods. Such higher-performance
>   implementations still must conform to the specification for Math.

For more information read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

Anyway, if you need better performance *-in this case-* you can use `double` instead of `Double` and forget your `getAbs()` and use `Math.abs()` directly.

Answer (score 4):

I just had a look at <strike>Sun</strike>Oracle's implementation and this is how they've implemented it

```
public static double abs(double a) {
    return (a <= 0.0D) ? 0.0D - a : a;
}
```

Except for the cost of unboxing and autoboxing params and return values, there shouldn't be any other performance impact.